# IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5 - jdk 1.7 shows invalid in project structure

Tags: java, intellij-idea

JDK 1.7 shows invalid in the project structure.

I am unable to auto resolve any symbol in my project. I am not sure if these two are related but can someone please help me out?

Comment: I can't see a way to answer this question without more detail. Is there no error message or warning whatsoever?

Comment: The errors in the project structure are : Module 'app': invalid item '<1.7>' in the dependencies list & Module 'app-build': invalid item '<1.7>' in the dependencies list

Nothing changes with the change in the jdk version

Comment: Another question is how do the symbols get automatically resolved in IDEA 11.1.5. In 13.0, there's a drop down which comes but in 11.1.5 i have to specifically import a particular package and it doesn't auto resolve. I am forced to use 11.1.5. :(

Comment: I have the same issue... any resolution?

Comment: Step down to JDK 1.6 and it works fine!